# Run lapply with lmer function on list of list

Tags: r, error-handling, lapply, lme4

I am struggling with launching the `lmer` function on a data set comprising a list of lists. I have tried converting the list as a data frame too, but it returns an error

```r
lapply(list, function(x) lapply(x, function(x) as.data.frame(x)))

lapply(list, function(x) lapply(x, function(x) 
      lmer(x[,4:7] ~ var + (1| id), x)))
```

> Error in model.frame.default(data = x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = x[,  :
> not valid type (list) for the variable 'x'

Can anyone suggest something for running `lmer` through `lapply`?

### reprex

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
require(writexl)
write_xlsx(mtcars, 'PQ_ele_com.xlsx')
        
dir = c('com', 'set', 'rit')
init = c('PQ', 'MG')
inpst = c('_ele_', '_mel_', '_col_')
           
for (i in dir) {
   for (j in init) {
      for (k in inpst){
        write_xlsx(mtcars, paste0(j, k, i, '.xlsx')) 
      }
   }
}
    
files = list.files(recursive= FALSE, full.names= FALSE)
     
init = c('PQ', 'MG')
dir = c('com', 'set', 'rit')
     
list3 = NULL
for (j in init){
   for (k in dir){
      df=c()
      for (i in files){
           if(str_detect(i, pattern = j) & str_detect(i, pattern = k)) {
             df=rbind(df,read_excel(i))}
         }
         list3[[j]][[k]] = df
      }
 }
```

Let's suppose I would like to fit `lmer` model through each sublists. For example:

```r
lapply(list3, function(x) lapply(x, 
    function(x) lmer(x[,3:7]  ~ vs + (1| cyl), x)))
```

It returns the error reported. Do you think it is possible to coerce it somehow?

Comment: You want to use a matrix as DV?

Comment: As @jay.sf suggests, `lmer` can't fit multivariate-response models. Is your goal to fit models with response variables `x[,4],` x[,5]`, `x[,6]`, `x[,7]` ?  Could we have a [mcve] please? Is `list()` supposed to be something like the result of `replicate(5, mtcars, simplify = FALSE)` (a list of data frames)?  Or is it a list of list of data frames? (i.e. do you want to fit a model for each response variable within each element of a nested list?)

Comment: @BenBolker I have provided it. Is there any chance to use the lmer function with lapply?

Comment: I still don't understand what you want your response variable to be. `list3[[1]][[1]]` (for example) is a copy of the `mtcars` data frame. If you run `x <- list3[[1]][[1]]; lmer(x[,5:10] ~ cyl + (1|mpg), x)` it throws exactly the same error you report - i.e., the problem has nothing to do with `lapply`. `lmer` doesn't accept a matrix as a response variable. Do you want to fit five **separate** models, one for each of the 5 columns you've specified?

Comment: I have tried to replace the column, the independent variable, and the random effect n the model, if that might be due to something wrong in the model itself. Your final interpretation is correct. This is what I would like to do, of course, if possible. If not, it is not a problem. It is just for curiosity. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stick a matrix on the left-hand side of a formula and expect `lmer` to fit a series of models using each of the columns as the response in turn. (This works for `lm()`, but only because of some special structure in the way that linear models are fitted and interpreted.)

So, you need another `lapply()` or loop at the bottom level to iterate over columns/response variables. Code below is one way to do it. To be honest, I might use `for` loops instead here, they're easier to debug than nested `lapply()` functions ...

```r
res <- 
lapply(list3, 
    function(x) { lapply(x, 
        function(y) { lapply(names(y)[3:7],
            function(n) {
               ## browser()
               form <- reformulate(c("vs", "(1|cyl)"), response = n)
               lmer(form, data = y) 
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you the code is nice, but does not seem to work my hand. I am getting as error  `Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :  not valid term in the model formula`

Comment: Is that with the reproducible example you've given, or with your own specific example/data that you haven't shown?

Comment: I have rerun it. It works great, thanks